# Add html to registration page

Tags: forms, users, theming

I have a registration form, and in the beginning of my registration page I want to show a title, subtitle and an image. A wireframe is like this:

[image]

As you can see there are checkboxes (select field) of my register form. But I would like to know how I can add the upper part to my page (Title, subtitle, logo).

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: If you are talking about drupal's core user registration form, you would most probably use hook_form_alter: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7 and "just" add in some `#markup`, eg https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup-attribute (which you would just use in your form if you are defining it yourself as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the theme you are using in Drupal.

[There is a good overview of this here.](https://www.drupal.org/node/350634)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.